# How to connect one class element to another class?

Tags: python, function, class, simulation

So I've been learning python for a few months now and decided to make a baseball simulation game.

So far, I have created 2 classes: Teams and Players. Each Team has a `team id`, `name`, and `record`. Each player has a `player id`, `team id`, `name`, and `position`.

I am wondering how I can connect the created Players to the created Teams and have a variable of the roster. Currently, I have a list of all created Players and have assigned them to 2 different created Teams. And then have a function of a for loop that puts all the same players with the same team id together. This is what I have that produces the outcome of the players and their position.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, player_id, team_id, name, position):
        self.pid = player_id
        self.tid = team_id
        self.name = name
        self.position = position
```

```
class Team:
    def __init__(self, team_id, location, team_name, record):
        self.tid = team_id
        self.location = location
        self.team = team_name
        self.record = record
```

```
def team_1():
    for player in players:
        if player.tid == 1:
            print(player.name, player.position)
```

Result:

```
Player1 P
Player2 C
Player3 1st
Player4 2nd
Player5 3rd
Player6 SS
Player7 LF
Player8 CF
Player9 RF
```

This probably isn't the best way to connect the two classes, but is there a way to connect the Team class to the roster like the Result? Is there a way to make an attribute as a list and put the players in there to link them?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [mre]. You should include the two classes in the question - at least enough of each class that is relevant to the question.

Comment: Seems like a Team should have an attribute that contains players on the team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this - here is a (hopefully) straight forward solution.

Add an attribute to the Team class to hold its players.

```
class Team:
    def __init__(self, team_id, location, team_name, record):
        self.tid = team_id
        self.location = location
        self.team = team_name
        self.record = record
        self.roster = []
```

When you make a player add it to the team.

```
team1 = Team(1,'here','us','inf-0')
p1 = Player(1,1,'me','concession stand')
team1.roster.append(p1)
```

In that case the roster contains a complete player instance. You may want to just *hold* the player id.

```
p1 = Player(1,1,'me','concession stand')
team1.roster.append(p1.pid)
```

Maybe you have a list of teams and need to find the team when you make a player.

```
team1 = Team(1,'here','us','inf-0')
team2 = Team(2,'there','there','???')

teams = [team1,team2]

p1 = Player(1,1,'me','concession stand')
for team in teams:
    if team.tid == p1.pid:
        team.roster.append(p1)
```